# Angular 2, how to get activated route globally?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

How can I get the ActivatedRoute in a component that is not involved with routing?

I tried like this:

```
constructor(
  private _route: ActivatedRoute,
) {
  this._route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {

    console.log(params['param1'], params['param2']);

  });

}
```

It logs undefined, undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
constructor(private router:Router) {
  router.events
  .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd) 
  .forEach(e => {
    console.log(router.routerState.root);
    console.log(router.routerState.root.firstChild);
  );
}
```

In Angular 6:

```
this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(r => {
  console.log(r);
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much! Hey that outputs a rather complicated set of objects. How would I go about getting parameters from that? And nested params?

Comment: `...root.params['id']` or `...firstChild.params['id']` should work. With above code you should get an https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html if I didn't mix stuff up.

Comment: Is there any way to get Router from within a service? My main service needs this info. Otherwise, my only option is to capture the router state in a component, and pass the parameters into my service, which seems a bit hacky.

Comment: BTW, I was able to get the info I needed like this:             console.log(_router.routerState.root.firstChild.params['value']['id']);
            console.log(_router.routerState.root.firstChild.firstChild.params['value']['id']);